# Power Apps (V2) Concatenated Combobox Values Not Seen as Text

Tags: text, concatenation, powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

I'm trying to send my combobox choices to Power Automate through Power Apps. I'm getting the values from an outlook365 connection people-picker and concatenating the values chosen by the user into a text string, then sending it to my flow through a Power Automate connector. The field I'm trying to send the values to is a text field, and when I highlight the `concat()` function to make sure the values coming in are as they should be, I can see that it is text coming in, and when I select the function, power apps sees it as text as well. However, when I attempt to submit the form, an error is thrown and it complains that I'm not sending text through that parameter.

[image: Power App (V2) Error]

Ok, so this got it to finally submit using `Concatenate("'",crsInpSupervisor.Selected.Mail, "'",",")`. However, when I look at it on the flow side, it's blank. I guess at least something's going through? I did notice some weirdness, though. If I set the CC field to "not required" on the flow side, the parameter on the Power App side is suddenly expecting a record instead of just a text value. When I provide the record, the parameter is blank on the flow side, but there is information pertaining to the person passed into that parameter in the Header information.

[image: Power App (V2) Error #2]

- I've tried hard coding text into the field and it successfully sent,
  so I know it's accepting text like it's "supposed to".
- I've tried `First(crsInpSupervisor.SelectedItems).Mail` with the same
  result.
- I've tried putting the value into a label, then passing the text of
  that label with the same result.
- I've tried `crsInpSupervisor.Selected` with the same result.
- I've removed the connection to the flow and added it back. I also redid the call to the flow after deleting and adding back. No change.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating your Concat() function to Concatenate()

```
Concatenate("'",crsInpSupervisor.Selected.Mail, "'",",")
```

Or

```
Concatenate("'",First(crsInpSupervisor.SelectedItems).Mail, "'",",")
```

Comment: Ok, so this got it to finally submit. However, when I look at it on the flow side, it's blank. I guess at least something's going through? I did notice some weirdness, though. If I set the CC field to "not required" on the flow side, the parameter on the Power App side is suddenly expecting a record instead of just a text value. When I provide the record, the parameter is blank, but there is information pertaining to the person passed into that parameter in the Header information.

Comment: Now try the First(crsInpSupervisor.SelectedItems.Mail) inside the concatenate function

Comment: Same issue, just blank on the other side :/

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change crsInpSupervisor.**SelectedItems** to crsInpSupervisor.**Selected**

Comment: Exact same issue, unfortunately :/

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a Text() function? Also have you tried to test this by just hard coding a string into your function for this parameter? - just put "test@test.com" in place of where the error is and see if it goes away. If it does not, we would have to look at what the flow is doing next with the value next.

Comment: Wrapping it in Text() doesn't work. Text() just converts some non text (i.e. DateTime or Number) into text. I've tried hard coding the value in and accepts the input.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your flow from the PowerApp and re-adding it? Sometimes those connections can get funky.

Comment: I did, no success there either. Just spent the last 30 minutes fighting with it, too.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but in your concat function you're using & around the Mail variable. What if you change those to commas instead?

Comment: No difference with commas.  I did notice some weirdness, though. If I set the CC field to "not required" on the flow side, the parameter on the Power App side is suddenly expecting a record instead of just a text value. When I provide the record, the parameter is blank, but there is information pertaining to the person passed into that parameter in the Header information.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a single choice field you can use:

```
crsInpSupervisor.Selected.Text
```

Comment: I tried, but that doesn't work for a combobox.